# Read USB card reader with Linux? OMNIKEY CardMan 3121 USB

Tags: java, python, c, bash, driver

I have this OMNIKEY CardMan 3121 USB, which is a card reader such as reading Belgian identity cards. I am now having it connected to my Ubuntu on USB.

[image]

How can I read the card data using BASH or Python or Java or C under Linux? Using `lsusb/dmesg` all I can see is the following.

```
Bus 003 Device 032: ID 076b:3021 OmniKey AG CardMan 3121

[364695.783762] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[364695.805281] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=076b, idProduct=3021
[364695.805288] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[364695.805292] usb 3-2: Product: Smart Card Reader USB
[364695.805296] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: OMNIKEY AG
[364695.805707] usb 3-2: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 192 microframes
```

Follow up:

Sample codes: https://www.hidglobal.com/Download-EULA?headless=&regionfree=&nid=14983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PCSC (Personal computer - smart card) which is a framework/architecture for accessing different cards and readers in an homogeneous way.

Brokers for different languages exist.
Here is a link for a pcsc python tutorial: http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.pt/2010/04/pcsc-sample-in-python.html

edit: on ubuntu install pcsc-lite