# Can i upload my java card applet on a non java smart card?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard

I'm new to Java Card and I'm working on a project where I need PIN secured smart cards for a healthcare project. What I wanted to know is if I can load my Java Card Applet on a non Java smart card (I'm trying to avoid the expensive cost which can pick 40 USD or even more / 1 card) ? If it is possible, I wanted to know some tips on how to make the difference between the cards and get their technical details (Type, Memory, Contact / contacless, etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095083/read-usb-card-reader-with-linux-omnikey-cardman-3121-usb . Maybe it's not exactly what you're looking for, but it could be a push in the right direction.

Comment: I couldn't get smart cards here in Tunisia so I'm trying to work on my expired Credit Card.
I'll get smart cards as soon as I get back to london next week but I need to get more information about what I really need for my project. What I know until now is that I need a card where I can store a PIN code and store some other medical informations.

Comment: @Stefan This question is asking something completely different than the question you marked it as duplicate with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, some smart card OS's don't have a JVM so cannot run a JavaCard Applet.

Comment: Do you please have any idea about the cards that provides a JVM and allow running a JavaCard Applet?

Comment: @Achraf Check out the members of the Java Card Forum for a list of companies manufacturing the Java Card OS. Of course you may have to deal with a reseller instead.